# Xcode bot reports no accounts registered

Tags: xcode, xcode-bots

> Error: There are no accounts registered with Xcode. Add your server to
>   your team in the bot editor.

I assume the "Bot Editor" is "Edit Bot...".

Under Signing -> Options I have "Allow Xcode to Server to manage my certificates and profiles" checked. My Team is listed under "Developer Teams."

[image: Screenshot]

This just started happening, it was working fine for months. Maybe something expired.

I've tried switching to the Xcode server account and ensuring Xcode is logged into my developer accounts (this worked in the past for some problems).

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by logging into the Xcode Server account, checking out all my code and ensuring it could build. This involved having Xcode fix the provisioning settings from within the checked out project.